# User Interface in wpf for a Custom Task SSIS

Tags: c#, wpf, ssis

I'm creating a custom task SSIS. I use the IDtsTaskUI Interface to define methods and properties called by SSIS Designer.

I want to use a WPF user control to create the UI. But the Getview method of IDtsTaskUI seems not accept WPF user control because it returns ContainerControl type.

Is there a way to use a WPF user control to create my custom task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since **ContainerControl** is a control from **WinForms** I would imagine you could create a WinForms Form and host a WPF control inside of it as shown in this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

As a side note: I also image this would create a rather slow user experience becuase you would have to load the WPF stack inside your WinForms based SSIS Designer

Comment: Ok Thank's for your answer. I'll do it in winform.